# Get value of dynamically generated text fields PHP Laravel 5 jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, dynamic

**EDIT** I tried `var_dump(Input::all());` and in included my form tags ans the table which the dynamic fields is placed to show that it is indeed placed before the closing `</form>` tag.

I have a Generate button which generates text fields based on how many items I want.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="numGenerate" id="numGenerate" value="" placeholder="">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnGenerate" name="btnGenerate">Go</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Submit
</button>

$("#btnGenerate").click(function() {
     var num = parseInt($("#numGenerate").val());
     var html = '';
     for(var i = 0; i < num ; i++)
     {
        html = '<tr><td>Script</td><td><textarea name="script'+i+'"> Content here.. </textarea></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Response" name="response'+i+'" /><td></tr>';
        $('#scripts').append(html);
     }
     $('textarea').summernote();
     $('#NumberOfScripts').val(i);

});
```

But when click Submit and I try to var_dump it in my controller, let's say

```
var_dump(Input::get("script0"));
var_dump(Input::get("response0"));
```

I always get `NULL` . All my routes is correct.

I tried `var_dump(Input::all());` but only gives me:

```
array (size=17)
 '_token' => string '7ImJ4CRq57xlF3jVhdNAMwHjxln86g8mvGqHLAit' (length=40)
 'CampaignName' => string '' (length=0)
 'QuestionCode' => string '' (length=0)
 'QuestionCode2' => string '' (length=0)
 'PoPrice' => string '' (length=0)
 'Oc_id' => string '' (length=0)
 'mis_status' => string '' (length=0)
 'qa_status' => string '' (length=0)
 'prod_status' => string '' (length=0)
 'Age' => string '' (length=0)
 'IsHomeOwner' => string '' (length=0)
 'CoveredAreas' => string '' (length=0)
 'PostcodeExclusion' => string '' (length=0)
 'Telephone' => string '' (length=0)
 'Others' => string '' (length=0)
 'numGenerate' => string '2' (length=1)
 'NumberOfScripts' => string '2' (length=1)
```

So I assume it's not getting the dynamic fields.  My post

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('question') }}"> All is inside the form tags
```

As I am sure that I am generating dynamic fields inside the form tags

```
                    <table class="table" id="scripts">
                    <!-- Dynamic Fields Goes here -->
                    </table>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: try appending new inputs to your form, serialize it and submit via ajax.

Comment: @mdamia should not be ajax sir. I need just a plain submit. thanks

Comment: Where are your form tags?? and you your post method.

Comment: try var_dump(Input::all()); then verify which fields are there.

Comment: @mdamia updated my question

Comment: @ImtiazPabel updated my questions, seems laravel can't get the dynamic fields?

Comment: @JoeneFloresca before laravel get dynamic fields,you need to ensure you generate those fileds.So after generate those fileds please check is that input has name,using inspect element.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel Yes I already did it. After I generate it it has name. Does the problem has something to do with append?

Comment: @JoeneFloresca i think you generate those input outside form.Please check this

Comment: @ImtiazPabel No. See my $('#scripts').append(html); scripts is a table which is under the form tags. The dynamic fields that I am generating is inside the scripts id. Which is a table inside the form tags.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel I updated my question to show you that the table is indeed placed before the closing form tag. Please check my question, the last update.